# Script not triggering after keyup event happens that updates data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify a script that has data attributes in a form's `<input>` using the keyup function. The data attribute that is changed is `data-cost=""`. I have verified the change is correctly happening from the keyup event by using Chrome's inspect element tool.

The problem I am having is the script that uses the data attribute `data-cost=""` is not updating when the change is made. I am not sure what to do to get the script to trigger after the change.

The script I am referring to sums up all of the data attributes named `data-cost` each time a  checkbox is clicked.

This is the html for the input:

```
<input data-cost="" value="" type="checkbox" name="f_2[]"/>
```

This is the `keyup` script, which also has `blur` and `copy` in it.

```
$(function () {
       $('#account_balance1').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
           var self = this;
           setTimeout(function() {
               var str = $(self).val();
               $("input[data-cost][debt]").attr('data-cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
               $("input[data-cost][debt]").attr('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
           }, 0)
       })     
});
```

Comment: can you include the script you are trying to trigger that is reading the data-cost attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark because i'm a bit confused about what you're trying to accomplish, but AFTEr the last .attr change, you would want to call your function that is doing the summing, like so:

```
$(function () {
       $('#account_balance1').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
           var self = this;
           setTimeout(function() {
               var str = $(self).val();
               $("input[data-cost][debt]").attr('data-cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
               $("input[data-cost][debt]").attr('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
               YourSummingFunctionName(maybeEvenPassSomething);
           }, 0)
       })     
});
```

On an unrelated note, once you have everything working the way you want, try removing the setTimeout part, i don't think it's necessary to what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Ok I will remove it. Also I am going to put up the other script in a fiddle because it is too large for this site.

Comment: no need, just call that function by name from the code like i showed you above... instead of YourSummingFunctionName() use whatever yours is called

Answer (score 0):

did you try using $(this) instead of this?

Comment: thanks but it did not work. The issue is not with that script, it does work. The issues is with the my calculation script that is not triggering after the the keyup script changes the data.